# How can i get the reference objects in spring boot with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, orm

When we use SQL with Spring boot, we can use hibernate and add @OneToMany relationships. It helps us to get the reference objects from another entity.

As an example, suppose Order and OrderDetails entities. When I query the Order entity, It automatically maps with the OrderDetails entity and it brings the whole document together. How can I do such a thing with **Springboot+mongodb**? Is there any easy way to solve this problem? Is it called ORM?

Comment: MongoDB (and other NoSQL) databases can have a performance advantage when embedding related data.  The concept you are describing is relational, and the question - "should I embed, or relate" is a common question.  I would encourage you to embed rather than relate (where possible).  But, to answer your question more specifically, yes, spring has the ability to relate data, but not the way you think.  You must use spring templates, and with it you can invoke an aggregation using $lookup (MongoDB equivalent of a left outer join)

Comment: see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html

Comment: see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-projections-aggregations

Comment: see https://newbedev.com/mongodb-lookup-in-spring-data-mongo